# A problem in adding / removing item from datalist twice or more

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening everyone,
so, I'm trying to let the user add a list of ingredients. there is text input where he can either type ingredient name or choose from suggestions list (I used input with datalist). When he clicks add button, the item is added to the list and removed from the suggestions list (the datalist). when he removes an item from the list, it is removed from the ingredients list and returned back to suggestions list.
it typically looks like this:
[add ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rccOp.png)
The code works well but only for the first time. when user removes the item from ingredients list then later chooses the item to be added again it doesn't remove from the suggestions list.. I think it's a problem in the "return" function..

here are the code snippets (try adding any item like "plastic bags" into ingredients, then remove it, then add it again):

```js
function removeItem(list) { //removes item from suggestions list
  var item = $('input#' + list).val();
  if ($('option[value="' + item + '"]'))
    $('option[value="' + item + '"]').remove();
}


function returnItem(e) { //returns item to suggestions list
  var optionVal = $(e).closest("td").next().children("label").html();
  var newOption = new Option(optionVal);
  $("#suggests").append(newOption);
}


function addIngredient(e) { //adds item to ingredient list
  var inputContent = document.getElementById("addIngreField").value;
  if (inputContent != "") {
    var table = document.getElementById("ingredients");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style.textAlign = "left";
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input class='removeIngre' type='button' value='-' onclick='returnItem(this) ; removeIngredient(this)'>";
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<label class='ingred'>" + inputContent + "</label>";
    document.getElementById("addIngreField").value = "";
  }
};


function removeIngredient(e) { //removes item from ingredients list
  var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```css
.ingred {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.addIngre {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.removeIngre {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.addSte {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.removeSte {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.removeIngre:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.removeSte:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#add {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#stepsTable {
  counter-reset: row-num;
}

#stepsTable tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}

#stepsTable tr td:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: counter(row-num);
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 4-18 */

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 19+ */

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* IE 10+ */

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 4-18 */

textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 19+ */

textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* IE 10+ */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Navigation-visitor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/addArtwork.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/footer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/menuBar.js"></script>

<table id="ingredients" style="text-align: left; margin: auto; width:400px; font-family: " Muli-Reg ";">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <p class="fieldTitle" style="color: gray; font-size: 22px;">Ingredients</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="addI">
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 50px;">
      <input class="addIngre" type="button" value="+" onclick="removeItem('addIngreField'); addIngredient()">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="addIngreField" type="text" maxlength="300" style="border: solid black; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; outline: none;  border-radius: 20px; font-size: 15px; height: 30px; width: 95%; text-align:left" list="suggests">

      <datalist id="suggests">
                <option value="Plastic Bags">
                <option value="colored paper">
                <option value="wood frames">
                <option value="Used Fabrics">
                <option value="Terapak Cartons">
                <option value="Hair ties">
                <option value="Newspaper">
                <option value="Cardboards">
                <option value="Pizza Box">
                <option value="Aluminum Foil">
                <option value="Cloth Hangers">
                <option value="CD's">
                <option value="Leather">
              </datalist>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right; height: 50px;">
      <button style="border: none; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; width: 80px; color: dimgrey; font-size: 22px; background-color: darkgrey; " class="fieldTitle">next</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add value attribute when creating option again. `new Option(optionVal, optionVal)`

```js
function removeItem(list) { //removes item from suggestions list
  var item = $('input#' + list).val();
  if ($('option[value="' + item + '"]'))
    $('option[value="' + item + '"]').remove();
}


function returnItem(e) { //returns item to suggestions list
  var optionVal = $(e).closest("td").next().children("label").html();
  var newOption = new Option(optionVal, optionVal);
  $("#suggests").append(newOption);
}


function addIngredient(e) { //adds item to ingredient list
  var inputContent = document.getElementById("addIngreField").value;
  if (inputContent != "") {
    var table = document.getElementById("ingredients");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style.textAlign = "left";
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input class='removeIngre' type='button' value='-' onclick='returnItem(this) ; removeIngredient(this)'>";
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<label class='ingred'>" + inputContent + "</label>";
    document.getElementById("addIngreField").value = "";
  }
};


function removeIngredient(e) { //removes item from ingredients list
  var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```css
.ingred {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.addIngre {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.removeIngre {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Muli-Reg";
}

.addSte {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.removeSte {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.removeIngre:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.removeSte:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#add {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#stepsTable {
  counter-reset: row-num;
}

#stepsTable tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}

#stepsTable tr td:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: counter(row-num);
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 4-18 */

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 19+ */

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* IE 10+ */

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 4-18 */

textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* FF 19+ */

textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* IE 10+ */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Navigation-visitor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/addArtwork.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/footer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/menuBar.js"></script>

<table id="ingredients" style="text-align: left; margin: auto; width:400px; font-family: " Muli-Reg ";">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <p class="fieldTitle" style="color: gray; font-size: 22px;">Ingredients</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="addI">
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 50px;">
      <input class="addIngre" type="button" value="+" onclick="removeItem('addIngreField'); addIngredient()">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="addIngreField" type="text" maxlength="300" style="border: solid black; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; outline: none;  border-radius: 20px; font-size: 15px; height: 30px; width: 95%; text-align:left" list="suggests">

      <datalist id="suggests">
                <option value="Plastic Bags">
                <option value="colored paper">
                <option value="wood frames">
                <option value="Used Fabrics">
                <option value="Terapak Cartons">
                <option value="Hair ties">
                <option value="Newspaper">
                <option value="Cardboards">
                <option value="Pizza Box">
                <option value="Aluminum Foil">
                <option value="Cloth Hangers">
                <option value="CD's">
                <option value="Leather">
              </datalist>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right; height: 50px;">
      <button style="border: none; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; width: 80px; color: dimgrey; font-size: 22px; background-color: darkgrey; " class="fieldTitle">next</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```